# Flatten (pivot) table into a three column array on a Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table which looks like this:

```
   A     B      C    D  
1 red   blue  green white  
2 blue  red   white yellow
3 red   blue  green white  
4 red   blue  green white
```

and would like to get a result like this:

```
col1 col2 col3
1     A    red
1     B    blue
1     C    green
.
.
3     A    red
3     B    blue
```

It is kind of the opposite of the creation of a pivot table.

Is there any way on how do this with a function or plugin in Google Spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data is in four columns, seed F1 and G1 with `1` and `A` respectively, enter in H1:

```
=offset(indirect("A"&F1),,column()-8+mod(row()-1,4))
```

in F2:

```
=if(mod(row()-1,4)=0,F1+1,F1)
```

in G2:

```
=if(F1=F2,char(code(G1)+1),G$1)
```

and copy all formulae down to suit.

Answer (score 1):

Old post. However, thought of adding my 2 cents.

If the data is in Columns A to D, then using the undocumented `FLATTEN` function should `unpivot` this data quickly.

```
=arrayformula(query(split(flatten(A1:D1 &"!"&A2:D),"!"),"select Col1,Col2 where Col2 is not null order by Col1"))
```

Answer (score 1):

After considerable time and effort, I finally figured out how to solve this.

Three different ways.

And with the added option of filtering out empty cells in the grid.

I am providing the answer I wish I had found when searching to resolve this problem with Google Sheets.

[Here's the Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NDc0uJAQG9F25TVwTvo35N4BtBLY5Y6M-jk2N0HqoLk/edit?usp=sharing) where I solved the problem.

---

**Source Table:**

Because the OP's choice of names for columns and rows conflicts with the naming scheme of the spreadsheet cells themselves, I've created a table against which I will provide the solutions explicitly identifying the particular cell coordinates.

- The upper left cell is A1
- The fruits are in A2:A5
- The days of the week are in B1:H1
- The values are in B2:H5

| Cell A1 | Mon | Tue | Wed | Thu | Fri | Sat | Sun |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |  |  |
| Banana | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 |  |  |
| Cherry | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 |  |  |
| Date |  |  |  |  |  | 36 | 37 |

---

**Target table:**

| Time Window | Day of Week | Grams |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | Mon | 1 |
| Apple | Tue | 2 |
| Apple | Wed | 3 |
| Apple | Thu | 4 |
| Apple | Fri | 5 |
| Banana | Mon | 11 |
| Banana | Tue | 12 |
| Banana | Wed | 13 |
| Banana | Thu | 14 |
| Banana | Fri | 15 |
| Cherry | Mon | 21 |
| Cherry | Tue | 22 |
| Cherry | Wed | 23 |
| Cherry | Thu | 24 |
| Cherry | Fri | 25 |
| Date | Sat | 36 |
| Date | Sun | 37 |

---

**Solution #1** (which provides a header row):

```
=ArrayFormula(
  QUERY(
    {
      "Fruit", "Day of Week", "Grams";
      TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",", MAP(A2:A5, LAMBDA(x, REPT(x&",", COLUMNS(B1:H1))))), ",")),
      TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(JOIN(",", B1:H1)&",", ROWS(A2:A5)), ",")),
      FLATTEN(B2:H5)
    },
    "SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 WHERE Col3 IS NOT NULL"
  )
)
```

---

**Solution #2** (which does not provide a header row):

```
=INDEX(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(A2:A5&"×"&B1:H1&"×"&B2:H5), "×"), 
 "WHERE Col3 IS NOT NULL", ))
```

---

**Solution #3** (which is three column-formulas and does not provide a header row):

*Column:* Time Window

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",", MAP(A2:A5, LAMBDA(x,REPT(x&",",COLUMNS(B1:H1))))),","))
```

*Column:* Day of Week

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(JOIN(",", B1:H1)&",", ROWS(A2:A5)), ","))
```

*Column:* Grams

```
=FLATTEN(B2:H5)
```