# Stacking A Range of Columns Into One (W/O 50,000 Limit)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

**The Problem:**
I have somewhere between 20 and 30 columns of varying lengths (dynamic and can change). I would love the ability to be able to stack them in Google Sheets.

I have found some solutions that work until you reach the `textjoin()` or `concatenate()` result limit of 50,000 or whatever it is. Those formulas are as follows:

`=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("@",TRUE,TRANSPOSE(G:AB),TRANSPOSE(D1:D5)),"@",FALSE,FALSE))`

&

`=sort(unique(transpose(split(arrayformula(concatenate(if(len(G2:AB)>0,G2:AB&";",""))),";"))))`

Again, these both work but are limited and I expect results as long as 200,000 rows long.

A simplified example is:

[image]

It would be nice if it rendered only unique values and ignored blank cells. Does not need to be sorted.

**BONUS:** It would be also very cool if there was a version of this that would only produce cells that have 25 or fewer characters in them!

Comment: Only include [tag:microsoft-excel] on questions about [tag:google-sheets] when the question is about  something that involve both apps like converting a file from one format to the other.

Comment: Okay! I am slowly learning. Thank you, Ruben!

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/72835/88163 (try using FLATTEN and QUERY)

Comment: That does solve the beef of my situation! Now I just need to figure out how to use a formula to filter out the results that are over 25 characters!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I believe I figured it out after parsing together some of the answers that I received for this one (thanks everyone):

```
=arrayformula(FILTER((unique(filter(FLATTEN(G2:AB),len(FLATTEN(G2:AB))))),len((unique(filter(FLATTEN(G2:AB),len(FLATTEN(G2:AB)))))) <= 25))
```

This does all of what I was hoping for:

- It takes all data within the range and stacks it.
- It also gets rid of any blank columns
- Finally, it gets rid of any phrases over 25 characters long

I hope this helps others in need of an oddly specific solution!